# Job Output keeps overwriting itself

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have researched this and I am aware there are similar issues on SO. However, there does not appear to be any helpful enough to solve mine.

Firstly, I am experienced with SQL however, we have recently acquired two interns. They have been with us one week now and they struggle with reading code, so I want to keep this (its part of their task team) to be as simple as possible.

Basically, the below code is part of a larger stored procedure which is ran as a job daily in the morning. It is supposed to save in a designated folder called GoodsIN as an xlsx. However, this is overwriting itself daily instead of producing a fresh XLSX file.

```
@database_name=N'master', 
@output_file_name=N'E:\goodsindata\Goodsin.xlsx', 
@flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 
1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name=N'Daily 
0900',
```

If anyone could help, I would really appreciate it, as mentioned we have interns in so ideally, this would be as simple to read as possible (initially, I wanted it emailed out but that was somewhat too advanced for them) I will have them reading SQL before the end of the summer!

Thanks as always Guys,

Comment: Well....the output file name is hardcode and static. Of course it is going to overwrite every time this runs. The most common way of dealing with this is use the current datetime as part of the file name.

Comment: Great advice Sean Lange. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the date (or some other unique string) or it will overwrite the file continuously.

```
@database_name=N'master', 
@output_file_name=N'E:\Rebekah\PaidClaims' + convert(varchar(10),getdate(),110) + '.xlsx', 
@flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 
1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name=N'Daily 
0900',
```

This will produce: `E:\Rebekah\PaidClaims07-31-2017.xlsx`

[Here are some other date conversion codes.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)